# Parse & Unity 3D : Update an existing row

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parsing

Using the example code from the Unity Developer Guide | Parse 
@ https://www.parse.com/docs/unity_guide#objects-updating

```
    // Create the object.
    var gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore")
    {
        { "score", 1337 },
        { "playerName", "Sean Plott" },
        { "cheatMode", false },
        { "skills", new List<string> { "pwnage", "flying" } },
    };
    gameScore.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                                       {
        // Now let's update it with some new data.  In this case, only cheatMode
        // and score will get sent to the cloud.  playerName hasn't changed.
        gameScore["cheatMode"] = true;
```

It just adds a new row and leaves the original row unchanged.
I guess i'm thinking Parse would do something "SQL like" such as UPDATE where primaryKey = 123.

Searching for an answer i found this code @
https://parse.com/questions/updating-a-field-without-retrieving-the-object-first, but there was no example in C#.  All attempts to port this to C# result in multiple syntax errors.

UnityScript:

```
// Create a pointer to an object of class Point with id dlkj83d
var Point = Parse.Object.extend("Point");
var point = new Point();
point.id = "dlkj83d";

// Set a new value on quantity
point.set("quantity", 6);

// Save
point.save(null, {
  success: function(point) {
    // Saved successfully.
  },
  error: function(point, error) {
    // The save failed.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
  }
});
```

Does Parse have some way to update a row that already exists using C#? And where is it in the docs?  And how can their own example be so useless?

Comment: SO isnt really a "Do this thing for me" kind of site.  You'll get a better response if you post the c# you've already tried and the error messages you received.

Comment: using the code from the Unity Developer Guide | Parse :

Answer (score 0):

One of the posts related to my question stated "retrieve the object, then write it back with the changes" and i had not the faintest idea how to execute the stated objective (especially after the epic fail of Parse Documentation's example code)

Here is what i have been able to figure out and make work:

```
var query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Tokens")
    .WhereEqualTo ("objectId", "XC18riofu9");

query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                               {
    var tokens = t.Result;
    IEnumerator<ParseObject> enumerator = tokens.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    var token = enumerator.Current;
    token["power"] = 20;
    return token.SaveAsync();
}).Unwrap().ContinueWith(t =>
                         {
    // Everything is done!
    //Debug.Log("Token has been updated!");
});
```

the first part retrieves the object with the stated objectId, the second part sets the fields in the object.  The third part reports all is well with the operation.

it's a monkey see, monkey do understanding at this point being that i do not understand the finer points in the code.

the code can be tested by creating a class named "Tokens".  in that class create a tokenName field and a power field.  make a few rows with Fire, water, mud as the tokenNames.   Replace the objectId in the .WhereEqualTo clause with a valid objectId or any other search parameters you like. Execute the code and observe the changes in the Parse Data Browser.

For extra credit create the class required to implement the example code from the Chaining Tasks Together section of Parse's Documentation.

https://www.parse.com/docs/unity_guide#tasks-chaining